# Creating Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list

I am learning about `LinkedList`s and I am slightly confused as to why people implement them manually like shown at the following link:

http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/03/linked-list-in-java/

Rather than use built-in methods for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
    linkedList.add("Item 1");
    linkedList.add("Item 2");
    linkedList.add("Item 3");
    linkedList.add("Item 4");

    System.out.println(linkedList);

    System.out.println("-----------------------");

    System.out.println("Added New First Item:" );
    linkedList.addFirst("First Item");
    System.out.println(linkedList);

    System.out.println("-----------------------");

    System.out.println("Added New Last Item:");
    linkedList.addLast("Last Item");
    System.out.println(linkedList);


    System.out.println("-----------------------");

    String firstValue = linkedList.get(0);
    System.out.println(firstValue);
}
```

I have been researching this for quite a while but I still cannot understand it. Can someone explain to me the difference between the example shown in the link I've given you vs the example shown directly here?

Comment: to learn i guess... writing those functions yourself helps you understand how the linkedlist functions. And I am pretty sure the in built methods also perform the same function.

Comment: Usually people only implement their own linked list because they are learning how linked lists work and they get homework to implement their own. In a real program, there is almost never a good reason to implement your own instead of using the standard `java.util.LinkedList`. You'd just be wasting your time writing it yourself and your own version is unlikely to be better tested than the standard one which has been used and tested millions of times in the past 20 years.

Comment: The link is instructional - students and those pursuing jobs in software development may be asked to implement a linked list during interviews. In actual professional environments, you'd generally use the data structure implemented in your language's standard library.

Comment: Thank You that is all I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Data structures are a common introductory topic for learning a programming language. There's a class in most computer science courses dedicated mostly to it. It is most likely that these tutorials about manual implementations are in place primarily for their educational purposes, rather than for the robustness of their implementation. Indeed, in regular use cases, I see no reason for using any other implementation than from Java.util classes when available...

Of course, the caveat being "when available" is very important. Perhaps you want some special feature in your Linked List class. This case would likely necessitate the need to make it from scratch, or use someone else's general implementation and modify it accordingly.

To answer your question more directly, though, I must say that there are a number of differences in the example you posted, and the implementation from the site you linked.

1. Generics: The Java.util.LinkedList class can declare the data type of the links in the list.
2. "Link" Class: the implementation from your linked site has this, while the Java.util implementation has no need of such a notion.
3. Methods: The Java.util implementation has many more methods available for your disposal than the implementation from the linked site. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for more info.

Comment: Like Jacob said, a Link list is simply a container handled in a certain way. If you want different storage functionality, you need to write your own. Your example is an attempt to show you how it can be done. The java.util functionality is usually the best way. I would study how java.util does it.